# Raster extent based on SpatialPolygonsDataFrame generating incorrect extent

Tags: raster, r, sf, rasterization, sp

I'm trying to rasterize data from Berlin's average price per parcel data. I've downloaded the shapefile from their data portal using an API with a function that generates an sf object, and then selected only the ID, the value (column `BRW`), and the geometry. here is the description of the object:

```
brw2003
Simple feature collection with 802 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 13.10962 ymin: 52.33956 xmax: 13.74145 ymax: 52.66066
geographic CRS: WGS 84
First 10 features:
            gml_id  BRW                       geometry
1  s_brw_2003.1001  160 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.53115 52...
2  s_brw_2003.1002  200 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.2037 52....
3  s_brw_2003.1003   80 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.56818 52...
4  s_brw_2003.1004 1500 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.42251 52...
5  s_brw_2003.1005  460 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.34401 52...
6  s_brw_2003.1007  400 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.58039 52...
7  s_brw_2003.1008 1800 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.43833 52...
8  s_brw_2003.1009  550 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.39865 52...
9  s_brw_2003.1010  140 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.50077 52...
10 s_brw_2003.1012  900 MULTIPOLYGON (((13.40922 52...
```

Then, in order to rasterize this data, I've tried to make a template raster based on the average block size of Berlin at 4.5 hectares = 45000 m^2. However, the raster doesn't crop correctly based on this code:

```
# changing to projected coordinate system
brw2003_ext <- st_transform(brw2003, 27700)
template03 <- raster(extent(brw2003_ext), resolution = 4500, crs = st_crs(brw2003_ext)$proj4string)

Warning message:
In showSRID(uprojargs, format = "PROJ", multiline = "NO", prefer_proj = prefer_proj) :
  Discarded datum Unknown based on Airy 1830 ellipsoid in Proj4 definition

> template03

class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 8, 10, 80  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 4500, 4500  (x, y)
extent     : 1422360, 1467360, 383443.4, 419443.4  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +units=m +no_defs
```

I don't understand why the xmin/xmax/ymin/ymax are all incorrectly placed, and why, at a resolution of only 4500 m^2, only 80 cells are generated.

I've wondered whether this was an issue because I was generating the extent based on a multipolygon or an sf object rather than an sp object, but neither option actually changes the outcome:

```
brw2003_ext <- st_union(brw2003_ext)
> brw2003_ext
Geometry set for 1 feature 
geometry type:  MULTIPOLYGON
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 1422360 ymin: 385091.6 xmax: 1466630 ymax: 419443.4
projected CRS:  OSGB 1936 / British National Grid
MULTIPOLYGON (((1445891 396577.3, 1445935 39656...

brw2003_ext <- as_Spatial(brw2003, cast = TRUE)

class       : SpatialPolygonsDataFrame 
features    : 802 
extent      : 13.10962, 13.74145, 52.33956, 52.66066  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs         : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
variables   : 2
names       :          gml_id,   BRW 
min values  : s_brw_2003.1001,    70 
max values  : s_brw_2003.2221, 18000 

template03 <- raster(extent(brw2003_ext), resolution = 4500, crs = st_crs(brw2003_ext)$proj4string)

> template03
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 1, 1, 1  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 4500, 4500  (x, y)
extent     : 13.10962, 4513.11, -4447.339, 52.66066  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

This still gives me an incorrectly cropped raster. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit: incase anyone wanted to play with the data themselves, here is my code for downloading this dataset:

```
########################################
# creating functions to download data from FIS Broker 
########################################

get_X_Y_coordinates <- function(x) {
  sftype <- as.character(sf::st_geometry_type(x, by_geometry = FALSE))
  if(sftype == "POINT") {
    xy <- as.data.frame(sf::st_coordinates(x))
    dplyr::bind_cols(x, xy)
  } else {
    x
  }
}

sf_fisbroker <- function(url) {
  typenames <- basename(url)
  url <- httr::parse_url(url)
  url$query <- list(service = "wfs",
                    version = "2.0.0",
                    request = "GetFeature",
                    srsName = "EPSG:25833",
                    TYPENAMES = typenames)
  request <- httr::build_url(url)
  print(request)
  out <- sf::read_sf(request)
  out <- sf::st_transform(out, 4326)
  out <- get_X_Y_coordinates(out)
  out <- st_as_sf(as.data.frame(out))
  return(out)
}

export_format <- c(
  "geojson", 
  "sqlite"
)

sf_save <- function(z, fname) {
  ifelse(!dir.exists(fname), dir.create(fname), "Folder exists already")
  ff <- paste(file.path(fname, fname), export_format, sep = ".")
  purrr::walk(ff, ~{ sf::st_write(z, .x, delete_dsn = TRUE)})
  saveRDS(z, paste0(file.path(fname, fname), ".rds"))
}

brw2003 <- sf_fisbroker("https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_brw_2003")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not totally an answer necessarily as I still don't know why this isn't working, but I managed a workaround by using a single polygon representing Berlin and including `filter(!st_is_empty(.))` on the shapefile containing parcel values:

```
brw2003 <- sf_fisbroker("https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_brw_2003")

brw2003 <- brw2003 %>%
  dplyr::filter(NUTZUNG != "G - Gewerbe") %>%
  dplyr::select(gml_id, BRW, geometry) %>%
  filter(!st_is_empty(.))

load(url("https://userpage.fu-berlin.de/soga/300/30100_data_sets/berlin_district.RData"))
berlin.sf <- st_transform(berlin.sf, 3035)

berlin_template <- raster(extent(berlin.sf), 
                          resolution = 216, 
                          crs = st_crs(berlin.sf)$proj4string)
brw2003rast <- rasterize(brw2003, berlin_template, field = "BRW")

> brw2003rast
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 171, 211, 36081  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 216, 216  (x, y)
extent     : 4531042, 4576618, 3253780, 3290716  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=laea +lat_0=52 +lon_0=10 +x_0=4321000 +y_0=3210000 +ellps=GRS80 +units=m +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 70, 18000  (min, max)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the **stars** package for rasterization:

```
library(sf)
library(stars)
brw2003 <- sf_fisbroker("https://fbinter.stadt-berlin.de/fb/wfs/data/senstadt/s_brw_2003")

brw2003_ext <- st_transform(brw2003, 27700)

brw2003_grid <- st_rasterize(brw2003_ext["BRW"], dx = 4500, dy = 4500)
```

BTW: 4500 does not create cell of size 4,500 m2, but cells of size 4,500 x 4,500 m = 20250000 m2. You should have cells of size ~67m to create cell of size 4,500 m2.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me towards this — I found it pretty late the night I was working on this project after I managed to get things working, but I definitely plan to use it in the future. I also realized that I was using the resolution incorrectly haha, ended up using sqrt(45000).